# How to append a node with children to an existing treeview with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI 2012.2.607.

I am trying to append a node that I retrieved from an ajax call to add to my kendo tree view. However, despite the node matching the same model schema, only the top node is appended to the tree.

Example Node:

```
id: "333-333-333"
text: "Node1"
expanded: true
hasChildren: true
children: <Node2>
```

Node2 is of identical format. However, when I attempt to call TreeView.append("Node1") only the top level node (Node1) is appended, but not Node2, despite the tree showing Node1 should have children. Please note that the tree has loadOnDemand=true.

Is append not supposed to add the associated children?

It might help if I explain what I am trying to do. I have a potentially large tree and therefore use onDemand loading but also server side aids to limit the number of nodes per request. I provide a special node that when clicked, makes an ajax request to get more nodes and uses insertBefore to add some more.

I now have a search method as well, which i use to get the exact path to a specific node. What I want to use is this path in order to expand and add nodes dynamically (since the current node might not be loaded into the tree).

Comment: I would also like to know it the appended nodes will still abide the loadOnDemand functionality, since they have all the characteristics of nodes retrieved from the server.

Comment: In Q3 release (2012.3.1114) Telerik fixed a lot of bug fixes on appending and manipulating `treeview` nodes. I do recommend you trying with the latest release.

Comment: Did it work? if so, you can mark the comment as useful in order to let others know.

Comment: Unfortunately we are in a code freeze for 3rd party tools right now, so I can't test it with the update. I've gotten around it by recursing.

Comment: For future reference, I tried upgrading to a more recent version of Kendo (v2012.3.1114) and it still doesn't work. When adding a chain of nodes (nodes with children), the initial node that is appended expands but the request that is made is looking for a node with null id. Not sure why but it does behave weirdly.